# how force an asp.net application in iis to show default browser login window for enter?

Tags: c#, permissions, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

i installed php on my windows server 2008-R2 and every thing is ok about that on iis.
i created a web site in iis (php) and put a simple script on it.
i went to permissions of that web site and removed all permissions except administrators.
now when i open that web site in browser a login window appears and i can login with administrator user's info.
but this way does not work for an asp.net 4.0 web application on iis and i can not remove network service permission.mean by removing that i have an error when opens that web site in browser.
i want to learn how can we show default login window for an asp.net application in two ways :

1. change permissions
2. by c# codes

really appreciate for viewing and attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove Network Service permissions from the website because this is the identity under which asp.net runs.  But this shouldn't have any impact on remote login to the website.

The solution to making IIS authentication work nicely with asp.net depends on what kind of IIS authentication you are using...

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9b619620-4f88-488b-8243-e6bc7caf61ad.mspx?mfr=true

This document has a lot of detail on how to make the various IIS authentication methods work with asp.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817643.aspx

One word of warning just in case... it sounds from above that you're using the administrator login to secure your website.  Many forms of authentication that IIS (or asp.net) implements don't use encryption to send username/password to the server you could be broadcasting your administrator credentials to the world. You should always use an identity specific to the website and make sure that identity doesn't have any sort of other permissions on the server.

Comment: would you please show other documentations about this issue. i am a little bit confused about msdn.  which authentication mode should i use for my purpose? i disabled anonymous authentication, but which user should i use for login? where can i define it? i test all users with no results.

Comment: What type of authentication do you want to use? The first document lists the options and various pros/cons. The simplest IIS authentication is probably to use Basic.  But really for a 'proper' website you're going down a dead end - and should be using asp.net Forms authentication which is nothing to do with IIS. I'm assuming that you have a good reason to want to use an IIS authentication method - if not don't use one!

Comment: For Basic authentication you just create a user on the server (same as any other user), but set them to not be able to login to the server itself (as this would be a massive security hole). Give them access to the files that run the website (i.e. the security tab for the folder that holds the website files).  This is all you need for an html website.  You then need to set the authentication mode in you web.config to Windows (see the second document about 1/3rd way down).

Comment: really thanks for help. (as this would be a massive security hole) -> where can i define and prevent this hole?  after that when i go to edit of Basic Authentication we should set Default domain and realm.  what are these?

Comment: You prevent the security hole by not giving the identity/user which you are using to access the website any other permissions on the server (such as logon access).  This is all done via Computer Management/Users.  If you're using a local identity/user you can leave domain/realm blank - I assume these are for referring to a user in a different domain (i.e. using a domain server).